# Does a Winforms Control raise an event when it is added to a form

Tags: c#, winforms, events, custom-controls

I'm working on some custom `Control` classes and need to do some initialization on them which is dependent on them being added to a form.  Is there an event that fires when this happens?

I think this sample should be sufficient to show what I'm trying to do:

```
public interface IMyForm
{
    ISomeObject SomeObject {get; set; }
}

class MyForm : IMyForm
{
    //eg InitializeComponent() as well as several others called at later points
    private MethodThatAddsAControl()  
    {
        MyControl newControl = new MyControl();
        //other initialization as needed

        //does this raise an event in MyControl I can use to call
        //InitializationAfterBeingAddedToForm()?
        this.Controls.Add(newControl);   
    }
}


class MyControl : Control
{
    InitializationAfterBeingAddedToForm()
    {
        //can't be done in the constructor because at that point FindForm() will return null
        (FindForm() as IMyForm).SomeObject.AnEvent += new EventHandler(SomeObject_AnEvent);
    }
}
```

This is turning out to be more difficult than I initially realized, and I think I'm going to have to combine the suggestions from Bolu and Mike Dour.  The problem is that while some `MyControl`s are added directly to the form in which case Bolu's solution works perfectly.  Others are added to panels instead of being added directly to the form.  I think I've cobbled together a solution involving Bolu's solution for the former case with a few modifications to handle the case where the event is being raised by the panel being added, not the `MyControl` within it, and Mikes to handle the case of `MyControl`s being added to the panel after the constructor has finished running.  I'll have to test this more tomorrow morning before I feel confident that it worked.

Error message requested by Bolu when I try using his suggestion in the designer:

```
Failed to create component 'MyControl'.  The error message follows:
 'System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'MyNamespace.MyControl' not found.
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignSurface.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSDesignSurface.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerHost.CreateComponent(Type componentType, String name)
   at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerHost.CreateComponent(Type componentType)
   at System.Drawing.Design.ToolboxItem.CreateComponentsCore(IDesignerHost host)
   at System.Drawing.Design.ToolboxItem.CreateComponentsCore(IDesignerHost host, IDictionary defaultValues)
...'
```

And the constructors in place when I got the error.

```
public MyControl(Form parent)
{
    _parent = parent as IMyForm;
    parent.ControlAdded += new ControlEventHandler(parent_ControlAdded);
    Initialize();  //does rest of initialization
}

public TimelineControl(Form parent, Panel container)
{
    _parent = parent as IMyForm;
    container.ControlAdded += new ControlEventHandler(parent_ControlAdded);
    Initialize();  //does rest of initialization
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the `ParentChanged` event.

Comment: This event isn't suitable because it the designer adds controls to panels before adding the panel to form its on.  This results in ParentChanged firing before it's possible to follow the Parent property to the form object.

Comment: When the parent gets set, you could walk up the current parent chain and hook the `ParentChanged` events of each parent along the way. That way you'll know when the parent changes for any ancestor. When a parent changes, unhook all you `ParentChanged` handlers (to do this, you'd have to stored all hooked controls in a list in the previous step) and then do the ancestor walk again.

Comment: I was able to get that to work.  Since I'm not doing anything that would cause ParentChanged to fire more than once per control I just hook the same code to the topmost control in the Parent chain if it's not the Form object I'm looking for.

Comment: That makes sense. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

1. add a new `MyForm` object in `MyControl`

   `MyForm pForm;`
2. pass a `MyForm` reference to `MyControl` when create it:

   MyControl newControl = new MyControl(this);
3. then register `ControlAdded` event of your  `MyForm` object

   `pForm.ControlAdded+=new ControlEventHandler(pForm_ControlAdded);`

Based on your code, it should looks something like:

```
class MyForm : IMyForm
{
    private MethodThatAddsAControl()  //includes includes InitializeComponent as well as several others called at later
    {
        MyControl newControl = new MyControl(this);
        //other initialization as needed
        this.Controls.Add(newControl);   //this will raise MyControl ：：pForm_ControlAdded
    }
}


class MyControl : Control
{
    Myform pForm;
    public MyControl(MyForm ff)
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      pForm=ff;
      pForm.ControlAdded+=new ControlEventHandler(pForm_ControlAdded);
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**
for the MyControl you want add to a panel, just pass the panel's reference to MyControl:

```
class MyForm : IMyForm
        {
            private MethodThatAddsAControl()  //includes includes InitializeComponent as well as several others called at later
            {
             //create a MyControl object and add it to MyForm
               MyControl newControl = new MyControl(this);
             //other initialization as needed
              this.Controls.Add(newControl);   //this will raise MyControl::pForm_ControlAdded

                //create a MyControl object and add it to MyPanel1
                MyControl newControl = new MyControl(MyPanel1); //pass panel reference            
                MyPanel1.Controls.Add(newControl);   //this will raise MyControl::pPanel_ControlAdded
            }
        }


    class MyControl : Control
    {

        //// for control added to Form
         Myform pForm;
         public MyControl(MyForm ff)
         {
           InitializeComponent();
           pForm=ff;
           pForm.ControlAdded+=new ControlEventHandler(pForm_ControlAdded);
         }

   ///now for control added to panel
        MyPanel pPanel;
        public MyControl(MyPanel pp)
        {
          InitializeComponent();
          pPanel=pp;
          pPanel.ControlAdded+=new ControlEventHandler(pPanel_ControlAdded);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is the designer smart enough to pass this to the constructor automatically if I did that?

Comment: I don't think your edit will work.  I need the IMyForm, and because the VS designer adds controls to panels before adding the panel to the form when pPanel_ControlAdded is called I don't have a way to get the form.

Comment: Actually it will if I modify it to pass the panel and the form it will be added to.  The designer is bombing at the moment, and the error appears to be that it needs a parameterless constructor, which unless I'm missing something kills your idea.

Comment: what is your constructor for MyControl then? Have you override it to take Mypanel and Myform references as I suggested above?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Anyway, glad you got your answer from Mike.

Comment: @Neolisk, can you be more constructive. Hope you are not down voting for the part after the *EDIT* as all those were further help based on OP's comments.

Comment: @Bolu: Well, compare to the accepted answer. The OP attempted doing it the other way around, you extended his attempt. Don't take it as an offence, it's just much more complicated the other way around, and less maintainable, especially if you extend this approach across the application.

Comment: @Neolisk,  Thanks for your comments, but I can't agree. I'm not so sure why you think accepted answer is the easier/correct way. That is your opinion, but you could further edit that answer(or post a new one), which could make your statement above more convincing. As based on MikeDour's comment on his own answer, it's more complicated in my book. The answer I had provided here could just be one line *use `ControlAdded` event*, all the other part was just supporting OP's further questions.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you implement a custom event in MyControl ?

This article explains the method:

http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/04/15/events.html

Comment: -1. Because there is already an event for that, see accepted answer.

Comment: Oh well, this was 3 years ago!